# how to declare a driver in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

In selenium with java we declare/initialize variable like

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

with ruby

`driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox.`

So can any one tell me how can we declare/initialize driver in protractor?

I have seen on protractor website, we need to use capabilities but didn't get how a driver is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is not need to initialize driver in protractor. It is globally available as `browser`. So in test class you can directly call it as

```
browser.get(url);
browser.findElement(by.css('cssSelector));
```

For non-angular pages you can use `browser.driver` instead of `browser`. It will look like this

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.css('cssSelector));
```

Please read it properly, it will clear your all basic doubts about Protractor. https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial